# Compute $\cos\frac{\pi}{7}-\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{3\pi}{7}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

> Compute $\cos\frac{\pi}{7}-\cos\frac{2\pi}{7}+\cos\frac{3\pi}{7}$

This question came after an exercise involving finding the $7$th roots of $-1$. The roots were $\operatorname{cis}\frac{\pi}{7},\operatorname{cis}\frac{3\pi}{7},\dots$

This made me wonder if I could somehow use those roots, along with the geometry of complex numbers, to compute the expression. Any insight would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: This is the question about the same sum: [How to prove $\cos\left(\pi\over7\right)-\cos\left({2\pi}\over7\right)+\cos\left({3\pi}\over7\right)=\cos\left({\pi}\over3 \right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/347112) Although there the OP does not ask specifically for solution based on complex numbers. (So perhaps the two questions should not be considered duplicates based on this difference.) I will add that I found the other question [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Ccos%5Cfrac%7B%5Cpi%7D%7B7%7D-%5Ccos%5Cfrac%7B2%5Cpi%7D%7B7%7D%2B%5Ccos%5Cfrac%7B3%5Cpi%7D%7B7%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 2):

As $\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos(x)$ this is the same as to compute:
$$\cos \left( \frac{\pi}{7} \right)+\cos \left( \frac{3 \pi}{7} \right)+\cos \left(5 \frac{\pi}{7} \right)$$

But denoting by $\omega_i$ $i\in{0,\ldots 6}$ the $7$th roots of $-1$.

You have:
$$\sum_{i} \omega_i=0$$
and by taking the real part:
$$-1+2\left( \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{7} \right)+\cos \left( \frac{3 \pi}{7}\right)+ \cos \left(5 \frac{\pi}{7} \right) \right)=0$$

---

The geometric interpretation is that the center of mass of a regular heptagon (the $7$th roots of $-1$) is $0$ so it must be the same for the center of mass of the projections on the $x$-axis of it vertices.

Comment: There is a typographical error in the first line:  You meant to say $\cos(\pi  - x) = \color{red}{-}\cos x$.

Comment: Indeed, thank you :-).